# Упаковать python

Tags: python

Есть входной *`main.py`* скрипт, который использует разные модулей, нужно чтобы в главный скрипт подтянулись все зависимости.
Естественно, если я использую *`requests.get`*, нужно подтянуть в *`main.py`* *`requests.get`* и все, от чего он зависит.

В итоге должен получится некий *`joined_main.py`*, не зависящий от других модулей.

Я задавал вопрос на [Habr Q&A](https://qna.habr.com/q/1141434), и не получил разумного ответа. Может быть здесь есть кто-то кто может помочь.

Мне не подходят *pyinstaller* / *nsis* / *py2exe* и другие.
`.pyc`, `.pyi`, `.egg`, и другие такие штуки лучше не учитывать.
Мне интересно есть ли что-то уже готовое, а если нет - то как это можно реализовать.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? Пока в Вашем потоке сознания не прослеживается суть проблемы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае вы **не сможете** собрать все зависимости в один файл с кодом на Python.

Банально потому, что зависимости могут быть написаны не на Python. Это также может быть:

- Байт-код самого языка (файлы с расширением `.pyc`)
- Файлы, содержащие типизацию (`.pyi`)
- Пакеты, написанные на C/C++ и вызывающие Python C API
- Динамические библиотеки

В итоге всё сводится к тому, что вам нужно некоторое окружение. А в этом окружении должен быть установлен интерпретатор, который сможет обработать зависимости. Именно это вам и предлагают *pyinstaller* / *nsis* / *py2exe*.

Comment: .pyc .pyi и пакеты на C/C++, динамические библиотеки не учитываются.
Пока что просто.